# how to generate XBF file in xaml application?

Tags: winrt-xaml, windows

My requirement is to generate the xbf files from the xaml application. For that I  am searching for the steps that I have to follow. Can anyone please help me in knowing about how to generate xbf files? is there any settings i need to change in properties? I have searched in Google and could find anything related to this..

If any link available, please share it to me.

Thanks in advance..

Regards,
Karthi

Answer (score 0):

XBF files are automatically generated when you create an App Package.

Go to Project -> Store -> Create App Package. Then, use 7-Zip or some other unzipping function (you can rename the extension of the created package `.zip` and use the built-in compressed folder tool) and unzip the contents to a folder. The XBF files should be in there.

Comment: When i manually build an application, i got the xbf files in bin output directory. But, i got the xaml files in bin output directory when i build app solution file via the command prompt. Could you please help me to get the xbf files when i build application  solution file from the command prompt?

Comment: Can anyone please update me the solution for the above specified problem?

Comment: So, what you actually want is to be able to build from the command line and have it generate the XBF, correct? If you are building from the command line, check out the folder `/ProjectFolder/obj/Debug/` (or Release if you're targetting Release) and see if they are there. You can also check the `/ProjectFolder/AppPackages`.

Comment: Hi Nate, Thanks for your reply. I have tried your solution. No XBF files were generated in bin/Debug or bin/Release or AppPackages folder.

Comment: Please help on this. Its a very urgent issue i need to resolve today.

Comment: One option is to use the [Xaml Binary Writer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.markup.xamlbinarywriter). You can then create a tool that manually processes all Xaml files in a directory and outputs the XBFs for them.